# Remove rows with minimum count sum

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I would like to remove rows which sum is less than 10.

**See edited post: column c is a character**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(3,1,1,3), b= c(4,6,8,0), c=c(5,0,1,3), d=c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"))
```

I have tried this:

```
keep <- rowSums(counts(df)) >= 10
df <- df[keep,]
```

So this dataframe

```
a   b   c  d

3   4   5   aa  
1   6   0   bb
1   8   1   cc
3   0   3   dd
```

Becomes this:

```
a   b   c  d

3   4   5  aa   
1   8   1  cc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(rowSums(.[1:3]) >= 10)
  a b c
1 3 4 5
2 1 8 1
```

Or, with your code in `base`,

```
keep <- rowSums(df[,1:3]) >= 10
df <- df[keep,]
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you check the edit with the dataframe? My error comes because I have a character style column. Can I choose the number of columns to apply dplyr?

Comment: Do you mean one of your number columns is recorded as a character column or that you have additional character columns that you need to keep out of `rowSums`?

Comment: When I run the dyplr it does not remove anything, and the "base keep" function shows me this: Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: And I believe is because column d is non-numeric, so I wodered if there is a function where you can apply the sum to the numeric columns only, or manually selecting columns 1:3

Comment: Yes, you can manually select columns. That's actually why I included the `[1:3]` in the first example. You can use the `c` function to select multiple columns that may be separated in your data too. If you use `base`, you can do the same using `keep <- rowSums(df[,1:3]) >= 10`.

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`:

```
df[-which(rowSums(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)]) < 10),]
  a b c
1 3 4 5
3 1 8 1
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you check the edit with the dataframe? My error comes because I have a character style column. Can I choose the number of columns to apply dplyr?

Comment: Have edited the answer to accommodate for the possibility that there are non-numeric columns. This way you need not know in advance which columns are numeric and which are not. You just subset based on those that are numeric.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `c_across` in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    filter(sum(c_across(where(is.numeric))) >= 10) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#      a     b     c d    
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     3     4     5 aa   
#2     1     8     1 cc
```