# Removing cases from a dataset based on count (or number of minimum times appearing in the column) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a dataset in long format with 30 total time points. Participants are required to answer a minimum of 15 surveys in order to be considered for analysis. Using the count function in `dplyr`, I can see the minimum number of times a participant has answered, and I want to create a subset of those cases who appear the minimum number of times in that row.

`df %>% count(SERIAL)` gives me a nice breakdown of all the cases and the number of times they appear, but I am unsure how to proceed further. I attempted various functions but can't seem to find one that does what I need.

I would essentially like to do what this user did, but instead of it being based on a value or sum of values, it would be based on the count, or the number of times a number appears in the column: [Remove rows with minimum count sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578291/remove-rows-with-minimum-count-sum)

Thanks in advance.

Here is the dataput from dput(df):

```
structure(list(SERIAL = c("U2M5WSUCU8", "WU12MQ43CY", "6D1ZPD9ED2", 
"U2M5WSUCU8", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "WU12MQ43CY", "U2M5WSUCU8", "6D1ZPD9ED2", 
"WU12MQ43CY", "U2M5WSUCU8", "W1QEQR7RVN", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "WU12MQ43CY", 
"U2M5WSUCU8", "W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "U2M5WSUCU8", 
"6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "U2M5WSUCU8", "WU12MQ43CY", 
"6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "U2M5WSUCU8", "5FP9GU9D9C", "6D1ZPD9ED2", 
"W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "U2M5WSUCU8", "5FP9GU9D9C", "W1QEQR7RVN", 
"6D1ZPD9ED2", "5FP9GU9D9C", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "WU12MQ43CY", "U2M5WSUCU8", 
"5FP9GU9D9C", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "U2M5WSUCU8", 
"6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", 
"WU12MQ43CY", "U2M5WSUCU8", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "WU12MQ43CY", "W1QEQR7RVN", 
"W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "6D1ZPD9ED2", 
"W1QEQR7RVN", "W1QEQR7RVN", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "WU12MQ43CY", "6D1ZPD9ED2", 
"WU12MQ43CY", "W1QEQR7RVN", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "RHW86GB11P", "WU12MQ43CY", 
"W1QEQR7RVN", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "RHW86GB11P", 
"6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "RHW86GB11P", "RHW86GB11P", 
"W1QEQR7RVN", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "RHW86GB11P", "WU12MQ43CY", 
"W1QEQR7RVN", "WU12MQ43CY", "6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "6D1ZPD9ED2", 
"6D1ZPD9ED2", "W1QEQR7RVN", "RHW86GB11P", "RHW86GB11P", "W1QEQR7RVN", 
"W1QEQR7RVN", "RHW86GB11P", "RHW86GB11P", "RHW86GB11P", "RHW86GB11P", 
"RHW86GB11P", "RHW86GB11P", "RHW86GB11P", "F3PY1UWKKH", "R31CUPSTZM", 
"R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", 
"R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", 
"R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", 
"R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", 
"R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", 
"R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "R31CUPSTZM", "VSLVZ3W69X", 
"VSLVZ3W69X", "3SWNKRRSFH", "HW5Q1WHHLN", "RAU7M16CG6", "711TU3SH1P", 
"7VRGBKUB11", "DBZUGZHPVM", "2GS9F6KQ7T", "34WKG4MPU5", "URX9PR2DWD", 
"6G1PP4BHDC", "NVFNX8KMML", "NVFNX8KMML", "WHUY2U76MN", "EP3HTRU5EM", 
"58ZXPUPL6L", "89H7YRCLNR", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "GX94723BNC", "VTK79NVKN3", 
"BTA61X75HV", "D6YBSX8VM6", "D6YBSX8VM6", "GSLLUEYWRW", "QL7582C3KM", 
"W977FY4SBL", "AWTBBS5XDS", "YFV565C137", "SY39E765C9", "DYVNPK5G3M", 
"D32S3QFQ1L", "NXRT1EHE4B", "KMQQXT8S8A", "3NGPF7DUEE", "3NGPF7DUEE", 
"M3H2H4Q3ZE", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "REERVR1XS9", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "HUZW8SU8T1", 
"HXEENZC9YF", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "GYLT7HK32G", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "95286H8NUZ", 
"MYP5EPCKSD", "N9KF5VLE13", "RMR4PCGMRN", "RMR4PCGMRN", "X4TCBPFPCU", 
"BSAQBMQUZS", "GWKCZRZTTV", "2ZR5Q8SVVF", "NBM6N4H8YT", "D9PUREHLQB", 
"D9PUREHLQB", "HCD71A5SEM", "DBZUGZHPVM", "Q8GF4BQA6S", "711TU3SH1P", 
"34WKG4MPU5", "NY2122ZWLG", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "URX9PR2DWD", "7VRGBKUB11", 
"3SWNKRRSFH", "KLPC6G4DL8", "58ZXPUPL6L", "8C2X261W4F", "VUGY39Q8SC", 
"YYK39G9RMA", "U9HLFZSWT6", "2G943XLH9S", "QNWK8VS45R", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", 
"EYL2BZ1HGT", "N9G5UR4N1N", "9D43C8GC9L", "NVFNX8KMML", "WHUY2U76MN", 
"KD7TAG32M7", "VSLVZ3W69X", "TG8WH46Q6X", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "6G1PP4BHDC", 
"RGMFDVA56M", "1PADU1BNPA", "VTK79NVKN3", "7VRGBKUB11", "3SWNKRRSFH", 
"GSLLUEYWRW", "3NGPF7DUEE", "QL7582C3KM", "YFV565C137", "HW5Q1WHHLN", 
"KHGWKR4G72", "D6YBSX8VM6", "Q8GF4BQA6S", "DBZUGZHPVM", "VN2XZZ2EN9", 
"NXRT1EHE4B", "KMQQXT8S8A", "HCD71A5SEM", "P87K2GMCHL", "URX9PR2DWD", 
"W977FY4SBL", "BTA61X75HV", "CUFVABH653", "NY2122ZWLG", "DYVNPK5G3M", 
"D32S3QFQ1L", "VR99S6H7KF", "SY39E765C9", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "NPG9P5VLWB", 
"QNWK8VS45R", "BSAQBMQUZS", "GYLT7HK32G", "HXEENZC9YF", "9D43C8GC9L", 
"TG8WH46Q6X", "UK8UXEENZC", "58ZXPUPL6L", "EYL2BZ1HGT", "6G1PP4BHDC", 
"9P4R3CXPSP", "HUZW8SU8T1", "RGMFDVA56M", "NVFNX8KMML", "WHUY2U76MN", 
"U9HLFZSWT6", "VSLVZ3W69X", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "N9G5UR4N1N", "2G943XLH9S", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "GTG2QEEG3S", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "KD7TAG32M7", "8C2X261W4F", 
"C1AQYDHHVA", "X4TCBPFPCU", "GWKCZRZTTV", "VUGY39Q8SC", "RQ8WK2VPRX", 
"RMR4PCGMRN", "95286H8NUZ", "2ZR5Q8SVVF", "D6YBSX8VM6", "REERVR1XS9", 
"M3H2H4Q3ZE", "YFV565C137", "HCD71A5SEM", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "KMQQXT8S8A", 
"GSLLUEYWRW", "KHGWKR4G72", "3NGPF7DUEE", "VTK79NVKN3", "CUFVABH653", 
"VR99S6H7KF", "P87K2GMCHL", "ABWRQV76EA", "XE6CSUGCEY", "NXRT1EHE4B", 
"DBZUGZHPVM", "BTA61X75HV", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "QL7582C3KM", "214Y2H5YFS", 
"TS557M6ZFK", "7VRGBKUB11", "NY2122ZWLG", "28CY6WMZZT", "D32S3QFQ1L", 
"DYVNPK5G3M", "Q8GF4BQA6S", "2GS9F6KQ7T", "L4B96P3N66", "3SWNKRRSFH", 
"SY39E765C9", "HXEENZC9YF", "WS3PMFU9KS", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "QGVKLSNKNK", 
"9P4R3CXPSP", "D9PUREHLQB", "HUZW8SU8T1", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "TG8WH46Q6X", 
"UK8UXEENZC", "SSL4XAKB29", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "XBQK87K43S", "8X2XF2XUQM", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "C1AQYDHHVA", "GUSMSX7R6F", "U9HLFZSWT6", "9RG32K3WPV", 
"WHUY2U76MN", "NVFNX8KMML", "3EY55MYPWB", "VSLVZ3W69X", "9D43C8GC9L", 
"GYLT7HK32G", "KD7TAG32M7", "BSAQBMQUZS", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "QNWK8VS45R", 
"MYP5EPCKSD", "58ZXPUPL6L", "X4TCBPFPCU", "1PADU1BNPA", "GWKCZRZTTV", 
"8C2X261W4F", "EYL2BZ1HGT", "CBUX2RC32X", "2ZR5Q8SVVF", "2G943XLH9S", 
"VUGY39Q8SC", "D6YBSX8VM6", "QL7582C3KM", "SY39E765C9", "W977FY4SBL", 
"ZTQNGP9NFB", "711TU3SH1P", "DBZUGZHPVM", "3SWNKRRSFH", "KMQQXT8S8A", 
"KHGWKR4G72", "HCHZUPH1VL", "DYVNPK5G3M", "HEVZZ7WZM4", "GSLLUEYWRW", 
"YFV565C137", "7VRGBKUB11", "6NF3HNFGVS", "CUFVABH653", "3NGPF7DUEE", 
"D32S3QFQ1L", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "P87K2GMCHL", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "Q8GF4BQA6S", 
"214Y2H5YFS", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "BTA61X75HV", "L4B96P3N66", "34WKG4MPU5", 
"VR99S6H7KF", "2GS9F6KQ7T", "NXRT1EHE4B", "8C2X261W4F", "98A6RYRWG7", 
"WS3PMFU9KS", "58ZXPUPL6L", "9P4R3CXPSP", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "TG8WH46Q6X", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "QNWK8VS45R", "C1AQYDHHVA", "9RG32K3WPV", "X4TCBPFPCU", 
"U9HLFZSWT6", "QGVKLSNKNK", "EYL2BZ1HGT", "VSLVZ3W69X", "KD7TAG32M7", 
"W5K5XTQEL8", "3EY55MYPWB", "2G943XLH9S", "4BDTBDBXSE", "P4NLM4V5LM", 
"4QXKE5ACM5", "RMR4PCGMRN", "HUZW8SU8T1", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", 
"SSL4XAKB29", "WHUY2U76MN", "GWKCZRZTTV", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "GYLT7HK32G", 
"2ZR5Q8SVVF", "UK8UXEENZC", "3NGPF7DUEE", "214Y2H5YFS", "QL7582C3KM", 
"M3H2H4Q3ZE", "VTK79NVKN3", "D6YBSX8VM6", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "DHZWD4HUAV", 
"D32S3QFQ1L", "KMQQXT8S8A", "YFV565C137", "P87K2GMCHL", "3SWNKRRSFH", 
"DBZUGZHPVM", "W977FY4SBL", "GSLLUEYWRW", "BTA61X75HV", "7VRGBKUB11", 
"L4B96P3N66", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "XMXHX2PLR2", "7E4CA63VRS", "XE6CSUGCEY", 
"SY39E765C9", "DYVNPK5G3M", "NXRT1EHE4B", "VUGY39Q8SC", "4QXKE5ACM5", 
"4BDTBDBXSE", "WHUY2U76MN", "CBUX2RC32X", "FQ2ARBHLGZ", "GYLT7HK32G", 
"89H7YRCLNR", "W5K5XTQEL8", "MYP5EPCKSD", "9P4R3CXPSP", "PBAQ3DC1YB", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "RMR4PCGMRN", "9D43C8GC9L", "GUSMSX7R6F", 
"P4NLM4V5LM", "HUZW8SU8T1", "QGVKLSNKNK", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "QNWK8VS45R", 
"3EY55MYPWB", "EYL2BZ1HGT", "RGMFDVA56M", "U9HLFZSWT6", "C1AQYDHHVA", 
"GWKCZRZTTV", "58ZXPUPL6L", "NVFNX8KMML", "2G943XLH9S", "VSLVZ3W69X", 
"7L3DFDDEQ6", "98A6RYRWG7", "8C2X261W4F", "KD7TAG32M7", "X4TCBPFPCU", 
"BSAQBMQUZS", "TG8WH46Q6X", "1PADU1BNPA", "9RG32K3WPV", "QRSWQ78E9W", 
"YFV565C137", "D6YBSX8VM6", "28CY6WMZZT", "711TU3SH1P", "7VRGBKUB11", 
"SY39E765C9", "XE6CSUGCEY", "DHZWD4HUAV", "GWLDPHBS86", "VN2XZZ2EN9", 
"Q8GF4BQA6S", "CUFVABH653", "KMQQXT8S8A", "GFMYCX8E9M", "GDEG537HDC", 
"214Y2H5YFS", "XMXHX2PLR2", "DYVNPK5G3M", "3SWNKRRSFH", "L4B96P3N66", 
"7E4CA63VRS", "W977FY4SBL", "D32S3QFQ1L", "3NGPF7DUEE", "HEVZZ7WZM4", 
"QL7582C3KM", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "DBZUGZHPVM", "KHGWKR4G72", 
"GSLLUEYWRW", "5AKBMQ77KA", "BTA61X75HV", "P87K2GMCHL", "ZTQNGP9NFB", 
"2GS9F6KQ7T", "VTK79NVKN3", "NW4BWWFELQ", "NCE6EK3D3Y", "7TL6XM1F64", 
"PBAQ3DC1YB", "HUZW8SU8T1", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "GWKCZRZTTV", "W5K5XTQEL8", 
"GYLT7HK32G", "U9HLFZSWT6", "CBUX2RC32X", "4BDTBDBXSE", "QGVKLSNKNK", 
"WS3PMFU9KS", "C1AQYDHHVA", "RMR4PCGMRN", "H1W9ZPK6MD", "4QXKE5ACM5", 
"2G943XLH9S", "8C2X261W4F", "9P4R3CXPSP", "98A6RYRWG7", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", 
"WHUY2U76MN", "NVFNX8KMML", "BSAQBMQUZS", "QRSWQ78E9W", "9D43C8GC9L", 
"VSLVZ3W69X", "2ZR5Q8SVVF", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "GUSMSX7R6F", "QNWK8VS45R", 
"58ZXPUPL6L", "X4TCBPFPCU", "TG8WH46Q6X", "1PADU1BNPA", "EYL2BZ1HGT", 
"9RG32K3WPV", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "95286H8NUZ", "FQ2ARBHLGZ", "SSL4XAKB29", 
"UK8UXEENZC", "RGMFDVA56M", "3EY55MYPWB", "P4NLM4V5LM", "D6YBSX8VM6", 
"Q8GF4BQA6S", "3NGPF7DUEE", "NCE6EK3D3Y", "5AKBMQ77KA", "YFV565C137", 
"711TU3SH1P", "214Y2H5YFS", "GSLLUEYWRW", "XMXHX2PLR2", "CUFVABH653", 
"HCD71A5SEM", "QL7582C3KM", "7TL6XM1F64", "3SWNKRRSFH", "KHGWKR4G72", 
"DHZWD4HUAV", "HEVZZ7WZM4", "DBZUGZHPVM", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "XE6CSUGCEY", 
"28CY6WMZZT", "7E4CA63VRS", "KMQQXT8S8A", "L4B96P3N66", "BTA61X75HV", 
"P87K2GMCHL", "D32S3QFQ1L", "SY39E765C9", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "2GS9F6KQ7T", 
"34WKG4MPU5", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "NW4BWWFELQ", "7VRGBKUB11", "DYVNPK5G3M", 
"RQ8WK2VPRX", "WS3PMFU9KS", "EYL2BZ1HGT", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "CBUX2RC32X", 
"9RG32K3WPV", "D2KNLCC99W", "4QXKE5ACM5", "RGMFDVA56M", "HUZW8SU8T1", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "98A6RYRWG7", "QNWK8VS45R", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "9P4R3CXPSP", 
"P4NLM4V5LM", "4BDTBDBXSE", "WHUY2U76MN", "W5K5XTQEL8", "QGVKLSNKNK", 
"7L3DFDDEQ6", "VSLVZ3W69X", "C1AQYDHHVA", "RMR4PCGMRN", "58ZXPUPL6L", 
"X4TCBPFPCU", "GWKCZRZTTV", "NVFNX8KMML", "KD7TAG32M7", "2G943XLH9S", 
"H1W9ZPK6MD", "BSAQBMQUZS", "1PADU1BNPA", "TG8WH46Q6X", "8C2X261W4F", 
"VUGY39Q8SC", "QRSWQ78E9W", "GYLT7HK32G", "UK8UXEENZC", "D6YBSX8VM6", 
"XE6CSUGCEY", "XMXHX2PLR2", "2GS9F6KQ7T", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "711TU3SH1P", 
"DHZWD4HUAV", "7TL6XM1F64", "214Y2H5YFS", "DYVNPK5G3M", "GSLLUEYWRW", 
"YFV565C137", "3NGPF7DUEE", "W977FY4SBL", "7VRGBKUB11", "HEVZZ7WZM4", 
"NCE6EK3D3Y", "CUFVABH653", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "KMQQXT8S8A", "DBZUGZHPVM", 
"KHGWKR4G72", "3SWNKRRSFH", "P87K2GMCHL", "D32S3QFQ1L", "VTK79NVKN3", 
"WDRSHTS9Q6", "7E4CA63VRS", "QL7582C3KM", "GDEG537HDC", "L4B96P3N66", 
"SY39E765C9", "2G943XLH9S", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "BSAQBMQUZS", "HUZW8SU8T1", 
"GYLT7HK32G", "EYL2BZ1HGT", "QGVKLSNKNK", "MYP5EPCKSD", "58ZXPUPL6L", 
"PBAQ3DC1YB", "P4NLM4V5LM", "4QXKE5ACM5", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "C1AQYDHHVA", 
"NVFNX8KMML", "VSLVZ3W69X", "KD7TAG32M7", "98A6RYRWG7", "9P4R3CXPSP", 
"WHUY2U76MN", "SSL4XAKB29", "QNWK8VS45R", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "GWKCZRZTTV", 
"RMR4PCGMRN", "TG8WH46Q6X", "RGMFDVA56M", "8C2X261W4F", "CBUX2RC32X", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "3SWNKRRSFH", "KMQQXT8S8A", "D6YBSX8VM6", "711TU3SH1P", 
"M1VHMR1AX7", "QL7582C3KM", "Q8GF4BQA6S", "XMXHX2PLR2", "GSLLUEYWRW", 
"DYVNPK5G3M", "DHZWD4HUAV", "YFV565C137", "DBZUGZHPVM", "XE6CSUGCEY", 
"214Y2H5YFS", "NCE6EK3D3Y", "D32S3QFQ1L", "2GS9F6KQ7T", "CUFVABH653", 
"HEVZZ7WZM4", "34WKG4MPU5", "7VRGBKUB11", "SY39E765C9", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", 
"8B4S7D6MBA", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "3NGPF7DUEE", "7TL6XM1F64", "GYLT7HK32G", 
"4BDTBDBXSE", "SSL4XAKB29", "D2KNLCC99W", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "2G943XLH9S", 
"EYL2BZ1HGT", "HUZW8SU8T1", "WS3PMFU9KS", "QGVKLSNKNK", "CBUX2RC32X", 
"C1AQYDHHVA", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "NPG9P5VLWB", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "P4NLM4V5LM", 
"GWKCZRZTTV", "4QXKE5ACM5", "NVFNX8KMML", "9P4R3CXPSP", "98A6RYRWG7", 
"7L3DFDDEQ6", "9D43C8GC9L", "X4TCBPFPCU", "KD7TAG32M7", "GUSMSX7R6F", 
"QRSWQ78E9W", "VSLVZ3W69X", "VUGY39Q8SC", "9RG32K3WPV", "H1W9ZPK6MD", 
"2ZR5Q8SVVF", "WHUY2U76MN", "QNWK8VS45R", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "58ZXPUPL6L", 
"8C2X261W4F", "1PADU1BNPA", "CUFVABH653", "D6YBSX8VM6", "28CY6WMZZT", 
"3NGPF7DUEE", "YFV565C137", "M1VHMR1AX7", "Q8GF4BQA6S", "3SWNKRRSFH", 
"711TU3SH1P", "DHZWD4HUAV", "214Y2H5YFS", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "XMXHX2PLR2", 
"DBZUGZHPVM", "L4B96P3N66", "D32S3QFQ1L", "HEVZZ7WZM4", "34WKG4MPU5", 
"8B4S7D6MBA", "P87K2GMCHL", "QL7582C3KM", "SY39E765C9", "KMQQXT8S8A", 
"KHGWKR4G72", "XE6CSUGCEY", "2GS9F6KQ7T", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "D2KNLCC99W", 
"4BDTBDBXSE", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "WS3PMFU9KS", "RGMFDVA56M", "QNWK8VS45R", 
"2G943XLH9S", "4QXKE5ACM5", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "98A6RYRWG7", "BNA6ZKQERQ", 
"9P4R3CXPSP", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "HUZW8SU8T1", "QGVKLSNKNK", "EYL2BZ1HGT", 
"QRSWQ78E9W", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "9RG32K3WPV", "9D43C8GC9L", "C1AQYDHHVA", 
"VSLVZ3W69X", "NVFNX8KMML", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "P4NLM4V5LM", "58ZXPUPL6L", 
"BSAQBMQUZS", "1PADU1BNPA", "8C2X261W4F", "TG8WH46Q6X", "VUGY39Q8SC", 
"GWKCZRZTTV", "GUSMSX7R6F", "3SWNKRRSFH", "CUFVABH653", "D6YBSX8VM6", 
"214Y2H5YFS", "711TU3SH1P", "28CY6WMZZT", "SY39E765C9", "KHGWKR4G72", 
"M1VHMR1AX7", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "QL7582C3KM", "DHZWD4HUAV", "YFV565C137", 
"KMQQXT8S8A", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "NCE6EK3D3Y", "ZBYYQCTVU8", "DBZUGZHPVM", 
"VTK79NVKN3", "2GS9F6KQ7T", "D32S3QFQ1L", "7E4CA63VRS", "P87K2GMCHL", 
"XMXHX2PLR2", "HEVZZ7WZM4", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "L4B96P3N66", "GWLDPHBS86", 
"W977FY4SBL", "WS3PMFU9KS", "58ZXPUPL6L", "4BDTBDBXSE", "95286H8NUZ", 
"QGVKLSNKNK", "CBUX2RC32X", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "BSAQBMQUZS", 
"4QXKE5ACM5", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "GWKCZRZTTV", "QNWK8VS45R", "QRSWQ78E9W", 
"9P4R3CXPSP", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "WHUY2U76MN", "VSLVZ3W69X", 
"3EY55MYPWB", "9D43C8GC9L", "D2KNLCC99W", "2G943XLH9S", "KD7TAG32M7", 
"C1AQYDHHVA", "X4TCBPFPCU", "NVFNX8KMML", "BNA6ZKQERQ", "1PADU1BNPA", 
"HUZW8SU8T1", "TG8WH46Q6X", "P4NLM4V5LM", "RMR4PCGMRN", "P87K2GMCHL", 
"D6YBSX8VM6", "XMXHX2PLR2", "KMQQXT8S8A", "28CY6WMZZT", "214Y2H5YFS", 
"Q8GF4BQA6S", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "XE6CSUGCEY", "HCD71A5SEM", 
"YFV565C137", "DYVNPK5G3M", "QL7582C3KM", "3SWNKRRSFH", "8B4S7D6MBA", 
"WDRSHTS9Q6", "CUFVABH653", "SY39E765C9", "DHZWD4HUAV", "7VRGBKUB11", 
"VTK79NVKN3", "HEVZZ7WZM4", "DBZUGZHPVM", "D32S3QFQ1L", "7TL6XM1F64", 
"L4B96P3N66", "NVFNX8KMML", "P4NLM4V5LM", "QGVKLSNKNK", "EYL2BZ1HGT", 
"PBAQ3DC1YB", "4QXKE5ACM5", "58ZXPUPL6L", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "98A6RYRWG7", 
"RGMFDVA56M", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "NPG9P5VLWB", "8C2X261W4F", "RQ8WK2VPRX", 
"9P4R3CXPSP", "CBUX2RC32X", "C1AQYDHHVA", "BNA6ZKQERQ", "4BDTBDBXSE", 
"QNWK8VS45R", "2G943XLH9S", "QRSWQ78E9W", "VSLVZ3W69X", "HUZW8SU8T1", 
"KD7TAG32M7", "X4TCBPFPCU", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "D2KNLCC99W", "BSAQBMQUZS", 
"TG8WH46Q6X", "1PADU1BNPA", "GWKCZRZTTV", "3SWNKRRSFH", "711TU3SH1P", 
"XE6CSUGCEY", "YFV565C137", "DHZWD4HUAV", "VN2XZZ2EN9", "D6YBSX8VM6", 
"XMXHX2PLR2", "QL7582C3KM", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "D32S3QFQ1L", "8B4S7D6MBA", 
"214Y2H5YFS", "HCD71A5SEM", "SY39E765C9", "DBZUGZHPVM", "KMQQXT8S8A", 
"CUFVABH653", "P87K2GMCHL", "H1U7SL95EU", "34WKG4MPU5", "7VRGBKUB11", 
"L4B96P3N66", "CBUX2RC32X", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "QRSWQ78E9W", "HUZW8SU8T1", 
"4BDTBDBXSE", "WS3PMFU9KS", "WHUY2U76MN", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "2G943XLH9S", 
"RMR4PCGMRN", "GUSMSX7R6F", "C1AQYDHHVA", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "9P4R3CXPSP", 
"7L3DFDDEQ6", "P4NLM4V5LM", "QGVKLSNKNK", "VSLVZ3W69X", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", 
"NVFNX8KMML", "QNWK8VS45R", "KD7TAG32M7", "8C2X261W4F", "BNA6ZKQERQ", 
"58ZXPUPL6L", "9D43C8GC9L", "X4TCBPFPCU", "GWKCZRZTTV", "EYL2BZ1HGT", 
"4QXKE5ACM5", "2ZR5Q8SVVF", "UK8UXEENZC", "W5K5XTQEL8", "HEVZZ7WZM4", 
"3SWNKRRSFH", "NCE6EK3D3Y", "XMXHX2PLR2", "214Y2H5YFS", "DHZWD4HUAV", 
"YFV565C137", "DBZUGZHPVM", "XE6CSUGCEY", "DYVNPK5G3M", "KMQQXT8S8A", 
"QL7582C3KM", "D6YBSX8VM6", "H2UC5TWWZ3", "HCD71A5SEM", "D32S3QFQ1L", 
"VN2XZZ2EN9", "SY39E765C9", "CUFVABH653", "7VRGBKUB11", "WDRSHTS9Q6", 
"VTK79NVKN3", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "8B4S7D6MBA", "H1U7SL95EU", "P87K2GMCHL", 
"L4B96P3N66", "HUZW8SU8T1", "98A6RYRWG7", "RQ8WK2VPRX", "QNWK8VS45R", 
"8C2X261W4F", "9D43C8GC9L", "GUSMSX7R6F", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "C1AQYDHHVA", 
"WS3PMFU9KS", "CBUX2RC32X", "BNA6ZKQERQ", "58ZXPUPL6L", "2G943XLH9S", 
"4QXKE5ACM5", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "QGVKLSNKNK", "WHUY2U76MN", "X4TCBPFPCU", 
"7L3DFDDEQ6", "NVFNX8KMML", "4BDTBDBXSE", "P4NLM4V5LM", "GWKCZRZTTV", 
"1PADU1BNPA", "EYL2BZ1HGT", "9P4R3CXPSP", "ZZ3SHN6LUS", "DHZWD4HUAV", 
"D6YBSX8VM6", "CUFVABH653", "XMXHX2PLR2", "YFV565C137", "Q8GF4BQA6S", 
"214Y2H5YFS", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "8B4S7D6MBA", "XE6CSUGCEY", "HEVZZ7WZM4", 
"QL7582C3KM", "SY39E765C9", "KMQQXT8S8A", "WDRSHTS9Q6", "3SWNKRRSFH", 
"34WKG4MPU5", "P87K2GMCHL", "L4B96P3N66", "QGVKLSNKNK", "RQ8WK2VPRX", 
"P4NLM4V5LM", "QNWK8VS45R", "C1AQYDHHVA", "4BDTBDBXSE", "9P4R3CXPSP", 
"NVFNX8KMML", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "9D43C8GC9L", "WHUY2U76MN", "KD7TAG32M7", 
"4QXKE5ACM5", "HUZW8SU8T1", "BNA6ZKQERQ", "VSLVZ3W69X", "BSAQBMQUZS", 
"7L3DFDDEQ6", "GWKCZRZTTV", "1PADU1BNPA", "X4TCBPFPCU", "TG8WH46Q6X", 
"V4MPYCQ1LQ", "2G943XLH9S", "58ZXPUPL6L", "RGMFDVA56M", "WS3PMFU9KS", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "CBUX2RC32X", "YFV565C137", "D6YBSX8VM6", "XE6CSUGCEY", 
"DHZWD4HUAV", "3SWNKRRSFH", "H1U7SL95EU", "7VRGBKUB11", "214Y2H5YFS", 
"Q8GF4BQA6S", "KMQQXT8S8A", "CUFVABH653", "8B4S7D6MBA", "SY39E765C9", 
"XMXHX2PLR2", "HEVZZ7WZM4", "M3H2H4Q3ZE", "QL7582C3KM", "DBZUGZHPVM", 
"34WKG4MPU5", "L4B96P3N66", "DYVNPK5G3M", "WS3PMFU9KS", "4BDTBDBXSE", 
"ZZ3SHN6LUS", "QGVKLSNKNK", "V4MPYCQ1LQ", "BSAQBMQUZS", "2G943XLH9S", 
"CBUX2RC32X", "8C2X261W4F", "QRSWQ78E9W", "RMR4PCGMRN", "9D43C8GC9L", 
"98A6RYRWG7", "9P4R3CXPSP", "GUSMSX7R6F", "PBAQ3DC1YB", "QNWK8VS45R", 
"4QXKE5ACM5", "58ZXPUPL6L", "BNA6ZKQERQ", "VUGY39Q8SC", "HUZW8SU8T1", 
"VSLVZ3W69X", "KD7TAG32M7", "NVFNX8KMML", "GWKCZRZTTV", "7L3DFDDEQ6", "H1U7SL95EU", "7DCPQX1W99", "VY978QX2TL", "YLV5SWEFHG", 
"H1U7SL95EU", "QGQZE5UUKR", "YLV5SWEFHG", "7DCPQX1W99", "YLV5SWEFHG", 
"YLV5SWEFHG", "YLV5SWEFHG", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", "A7CAGBMTCN", "FRE78WXVVD", 
"ZH4K5Q98EQ", "A7CAGBMTCN", "FRE78WXVVD", "A7CAGBMTCN", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", 
"YHRXX4SM6W", "FRE78WXVVD", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", "A7CAGBMTCN", "YHRXX4SM6W", 
"A7CAGBMTCN", "FRE78WXVVD", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", "FRE78WXVVD", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", 
"A7CAGBMTCN", "FRE78WXVVD", "A7CAGBMTCN", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", "YHRXX4SM6W", 
"ZH4K5Q98EQ", "FRE78WXVVD", "TNCXMMMS8E", "A7CAGBMTCN", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", 
"YHRXX4SM6W", "FRE78WXVVD", "A7CAGBMTCN", "TNCXMMMS8E", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", 
"YHRXX4SM6W", "FRE78WXVVD", "ZH4K5Q98EQ", "TNCXMMMS8E", "A7CAGBMTCN", 
"TNCXMMMS8E", "A7CAGBMTCN", "A7CAGBMTCN", "YHRXX4SM6W", "TNCXMMMS8E", 
"A7CAGBMTCN", "TNCXMMMS8E", "CHYB227GSK", "WFNGXZGU9F", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"WFNGXZGU9F", "AUMZLBBX99", "WFNGXZGU9F", "AUMZLBBX99", "WFNGXZGU9F", 
"AUMZLBBX99", "TNCXMMMS8E", "A7CAGBMTCN", "WFNGXZGU9F", "TNCXMMMS8E", 
"AUMZLBBX99", "WFNGXZGU9F", "2UKFDTC2CC", "TNCXMMMS8E", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"WFNGXZGU9F", "TNCXMMMS8E", "VT7T8FZ3HH", "AUMZLBBX99", "WFNGXZGU9F", 
"VT7T8FZ3HH", "TNCXMMMS8E", "AUMZLBBX99", "AUMZLBBX99", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"2UKFDTC2CC", "L3BK7HQCCG", "AUMZLBBX99", "L3BK7HQCCG", "2UKFDTC2CC", 
"AUMZLBBX99", "YB2WEYGGD3", "5QU8EGXUBX", "DHVZ3BQWSL", "VXQEB4UZ2K", 
"2UKFDTC2CC", "CR9CZAGTQC", "YB2WEYGGD3", "5QU8EGXUBX", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"DHVZ3BQWSL", "86FRG38731", "HTRH2T7F9G", "2UKFDTC2CC", "2Q6Z16NWAT", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "5QU8EGXUBX", "BTY57UEMEG", "AUMZLBBX99", "DHVZ3BQWSL", 
"86FRG38731", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "CR9CZAGTQC", "VXQEB4UZ2K", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"8FGKYWVXHU", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "VVML2TUDCL", "5QU8EGXUBX", "DHVZ3BQWSL", 
"AUMZLBBX99", "APB4XD1L4C", "BTY57UEMEG", "86FRG38731", "8FGKYWVXHU", 
"LFAL4HTT47", "HTRH2T7F9G", "ECKVGPUUV9", "89GMM7HXQ3", "XX23WWRTAL", 
"VXQEB4UZ2K", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "2UKFDTC2CC", "VQSR42SL56", "5QU8EGXUBX", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "WKP5871S4Y", "YB2WEYGGD3", "APB4XD1L4C", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"WDZ5GHD54Y", "A2NQ5QCKUP", "BTY57UEMEG", "89GMM7HXQ3", "ECKVGPUUV9", 
"8FGKYWVXHU", "86FRG38731", "XM8N7TU66H", "2Q6Z16NWAT", "VXQEB4UZ2K", 
"HTRH2T7F9G", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "LFAL4HTT47", "2UKFDTC2CC", "CR9CZAGTQC", 
"EAY1YA7VA1", "XX23WWRTAL", "L24UXR2W2G", "VVML2TUDCL", "BTY57UEMEG", 
"9K67BSQN6B", "VQSR42SL56", "AUMZLBBX99", "VDS4N9DUDN", "DHVZ3BQWSL", 
"86FRG38731", "HTRH2T7F9G", "P6EN7YBCXL", "8FGKYWVXHU", "4BYQZKAR81", 
"KEMP9Q6BNX", "NTD4AKASA5", "89GMM7HXQ3", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "EAY1YA7VA1", 
"2UKFDTC2CC", "TNCXMMMS8E", "9K67BSQN6B", "L24UXR2W2G", "BTY57UEMEG", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "AUMZLBBX99", "VDS4N9DUDN", "5QU8EGXUBX", 
"DHVZ3BQWSL", "8FGKYWVXHU", "86FRG38731", "P6EN7YBCXL", "NTD4AKASA5", 
"4BYQZKAR81", "ECKVGPUUV9", "HLPN4N9KS4", "XM8N7TU66H", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"KEMP9Q6BNX", "VB9CQ65Z5S", "YG61GRTXAM", "D1ANAFHSD1", "VVML2TUDCL", 
"L24UXR2W2G", "GRADQPHVXP", "AUMZLBBX99", "D97CECY7X3", "VDS4N9DUDN", 
"WDZ5GHD54Y", "BTY57UEMEG", "9K67BSQN6B", "NM974PCUUX", "8FGKYWVXHU", 
"EAY1YA7VA1", "QNTND8CKX5", "ECKVGPUUV9", "P46YETAZEK", "4BYQZKAR81", 
"VXQEB4UZ2K", "9W4E9ZPC21", "9KQ4S6UDBQ", "KEMP9Q6BNX", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"5QU8EGXUBX", "ZZ6NTLFFX6", "YG61GRTXAM", "9K67BSQN6B", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"NQABR2FA6T", "VVML2TUDCL", "WKP5871S4Y", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "L24UXR2W2G", 
"D97CECY7X3", "VDS4N9DUDN", "GRADQPHVXP", "2UKFDTC2CC", "DHVZ3BQWSL", 
"BTY57UEMEG", "D1ANAFHSD1", "9KQ4S6UDBQ", "EAY1YA7VA1", "4BYQZKAR81", 
"8FGKYWVXHU", "ECKVGPUUV9", "89GMM7HXQ3", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "P6EN7YBCXL", 
"HTRH2T7F9G", "YG61GRTXAM", "5QU8EGXUBX", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "L24UXR2W2G", 
"D97CECY7X3", "BTY57UEMEG", "DHVZ3BQWSL", "9K67BSQN6B", "GRADQPHVXP", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "VDS4N9DUDN", "8FGKYWVXHU", "89GMM7HXQ3", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"4BYQZKAR81", "EAY1YA7VA1", "XM8N7TU66H", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "3K588UXZAA", 
"9K67BSQN6B", "YD168YAUHE", "VVML2TUDCL", "D97CECY7X3", "L24UXR2W2G", 
"UKTU8NFMG5", "ECKVGPUUV9", "GRADQPHVXP", "BTY57UEMEG", "VDS4N9DUDN", 
"2UKFDTC2CC", "D1ANAFHSD1", "3K588UXZAA", "8FGKYWVXHU", "89GMM7HXQ3", 
"EAY1YA7VA1", "NTD4AKASA5", "HTRH2T7F9G", "4BYQZKAR81", "1XR4KTZ4ZF", 
"5QU8EGXUBX", "1QYWWWWVYG", "4P9HAZDWWE", "N2SYN39CKV", "B7L6T4DFR8", 
"SZMXBGSESP", "BTY57UEMEG", "L24UXR2W2G", "GRADQPHVXP", "VVML2TUDCL", 
"9K67BSQN6B", "54N22PU3FE", "UKTU8NFMG5", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "D97CECY7X3", 
"RF9K958FTX", "HTRH2T7F9G", "8FGKYWVXHU", "1QYWWWWVYG", "U5Q7EQMUVS", 
"ACHFVL81GC", "VXQEB4UZ2K", "4BYQZKAR81", "XP21SPSTTK", "EAY1YA7VA1", 
"NRZQE4QTNX", "QNTND8CKX5", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "C8VX87QY2B", "L24UXR2W2G", 
"2UKFDTC2CC", "UKTU8NFMG5", "D1ANAFHSD1", "HH658D7SMH", "MWMABXFFZP", 
"WDZ5GHD54Y", "YD168YAUHE", "VVML2TUDCL", "D97CECY7X3", "GRADQPHVXP", 
"54N22PU3FE", "BTY57UEMEG", "DHVZ3BQWSL", "8FGKYWVXHU", "5QU8EGXUBX", 
"ACHFVL81GC", "W2BV5HPTLV", "P6D1DYW1QY", "1XR4KTZ4ZF", "WLFG8ZWB9C", 
"NRZQE4QTNX", "6QWDLRKVAT", "EAY1YA7VA1", "XP21SPSTTK", "4LSPSRD6YS", 
"FVRTMX5FGW", "HTRH2T7F9G", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "1QYWWWWVYG", "SSPNGMGXLY", 
"89GMM7HXQ3", "4P9HAZDWWE", "LZ1114TSZ3", "9K67BSQN6B", "WDZ5GHD54Y", 
"D97CECY7X3", "C8VX87QY2B", "MWMABXFFZP", "VVML2TUDCL", "HH658D7SMH", 
"54N22PU3FE", "L24UXR2W2G", "BTY57UEMEG", "GRADQPHVXP", "VB41KWRERL", 
"UKTU8NFMG5", "2UKFDTC2CC", "YD168YAUHE", "DHVZ3BQWSL", "FVRTMX5FGW", 
"4LSPSRD6YS", "HTRH2T7F9G", "8FGKYWVXHU", "4W35ENL7M9", "XP21SPSTTK", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "RMGQEV5WQG", "P6D1DYW1QY", "6QWDLRKVAT", "MUHCTAG2P5", 
"1ZNVL8WTS4", "17X8N3R48S", "5QU8EGXUBX", "1QYWWWWVYG", "SSPNGMGXLY", 
"8NQLXTPGRB", "V2GZY6SZ7C", "C8VX87QY2B", "NQABR2FA6T", "D97CECY7X3", 
"HH658D7SMH", "MWMABXFFZP", "9K67BSQN6B", "L24UXR2W2G", "54N22PU3FE", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "EKH3KN6Z91", "BTY57UEMEG", "UKTU8NFMG5", "2UKFDTC2CC", 
"XTGMRCYC5H", "W2BV5HPTLV", "FVRTMX5FGW", "XP21SPSTTK", "4LSPSRD6YS", 
"89GMM7HXQ3", "HTRH2T7F9G", "EAY1YA7VA1", "8FGKYWVXHU", "ULRGP54HCB", 
"31QBK8V3W4", "17X8N3R48S", "MUHCTAG2P5", "4GPMWXTXZT", "1ZNVL8WTS4", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "P6D1DYW1QY", "DHVZ3BQWSL", "1QYWWWWVYG", "1XR4KTZ4ZF", 
"SSPNGMGXLY", "XTGMRCYC5H", "HH658D7SMH", "459W995DKU", "Q7CX6BFYQ6", 
"2UKFDTC2CC", "2DSTDKLEH5", "54N22PU3FE", "VVML2TUDCL", "C8VX87QY2B", 
"GRADQPHVXP", "CLXM29YBRY", "BTY57UEMEG", "UKTU8NFMG5", "EKH3KN6Z91", 
"9K67BSQN6B", "YD168YAUHE", "QYC4K7T1MV", "5QU8EGXUBX", "L24UXR2W2G", 
"3VRZDQHSUG", "8NQLXTPGRB", "VXQEB4UZ2K", "8FGKYWVXHU", "17X8N3R48S", 
"4LSPSRD6YS", "FVRTMX5FGW", "MUHCTAG2P5", "SSPNGMGXLY", "4GPMWXTXZT", 
"ULRGP54HCB", "LZ1114TSZ3", "HTRH2T7F9G", "89GMM7HXQ3", "P6D1DYW1QY", 
"LMUPB2T62S", "XP21SPSTTK", "WLFG8ZWB9C", "3G7HPWYYXM", "XM8N7TU66H", 
"8NQLXTPGRB", "XTGMRCYC5H", "D97CECY7X3", "CLXM29YBRY", "Q7CX6BFYQ6", 
"9K67BSQN6B", "C8VX87QY2B", "54N22PU3FE", "L24UXR2W2G", "VVML2TUDCL", 
"617Y39C1HC", "GRADQPHVXP", "459W995DKU", "K4NHG395WP", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"5QU8EGXUBX", "BTY57UEMEG", "YD168YAUHE", "2UKFDTC2CC", "8FGKYWVXHU", 
"4LSPSRD6YS", "MUHCTAG2P5", "EAY1YA7VA1", "4GPMWXTXZT", "FVRTMX5FGW", 
"P6D1DYW1QY", "SSPNGMGXLY", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "HTRH2T7F9G", "ULRGP54HCB", 
"XP21SPSTTK", "17X8N3R48S", "LZ1114TSZ3", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "3G7HPWYYXM", 
"RMGQEV5WQG", "L24UXR2W2G", "VVML2TUDCL", "AUMZLBBX99", "9K67BSQN6B", 
"K4NHG395WP", "4B7NMQL8SQ", "Q7CX6BFYQ6", "5QU8EGXUBX", "54N22PU3FE", 
"459W995DKU", "BTY57UEMEG", "D97CECY7X3", "EKH3KN6Z91", "8NQLXTPGRB", 
"GRADQPHVXP", "4LSPSRD6YS", "HH658D7SMH", "P6D1DYW1QY", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "4GPMWXTXZT", "ULRGP54HCB", "FVRTMX5FGW", "4LC6PYB1NU", 
"XP21SPSTTK", "EAY1YA7VA1", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "YD168YAUHE", 
"17X8N3R48S", "8FGKYWVXHU", "MUHCTAG2P5", "1XR4KTZ4ZF", "SSPNGMGXLY", 
"L24UXR2W2G", "AUMZLBBX99", "D97CECY7X3", "VVML2TUDCL", "54N22PU3FE", 
"K4NHG395WP", "459W995DKU", "8NQLXTPGRB", "4B7NMQL8SQ", "AHZHB4PYA3", 
"EKH3KN6Z91", "5QU8EGXUBX", "BTY57UEMEG", "4GPMWXTXZT", "4LSPSRD6YS", 
"P6D1DYW1QY", "MUHCTAG2P5", "FVRTMX5FGW", "EAY1YA7VA1", "8FGKYWVXHU", 
"HTRH2T7F9G", "XP21SPSTTK", "W2BV5HPTLV", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "LZ1114TSZ3", 
"3G7HPWYYXM", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "17X8N3R48S", "ULRGP54HCB", "RMGQEV5WQG", 
"AHZHB4PYA3", "K4NHG395WP", "8NQLXTPGRB", "AUMZLBBX99", "D97CECY7X3", 
"SSPNGMGXLY", "VVML2TUDCL", "L24UXR2W2G", "54N22PU3FE", "GRADQPHVXP", 
"EKH3KN6Z91", "BTY57UEMEG", "2UKFDTC2CC", "5QU8EGXUBX", "4LSPSRD6YS", 
"WDZ5GHD54Y", "4GPMWXTXZT", "MUHCTAG2P5", "FVRTMX5FGW", "EAY1YA7VA1", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "ULRGP54HCB", "DHVZ3BQWSL", "8FGKYWVXHU", "XP21SPSTTK", 
"P6D1DYW1QY", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "YD168YAUHE", "17X8N3R48S", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"RMGQEV5WQG", "K4NHG395WP", "AHZHB4PYA3", "VVML2TUDCL", "L24UXR2W2G", 
"D97CECY7X3", "EKH3KN6Z91", "SSPNGMGXLY", "UKTU8NFMG5", "AUMZLBBX99", 
"GRADQPHVXP", "8NQLXTPGRB", "5QU8EGXUBX", "459W995DKU", "BTY57UEMEG", 
"2UKFDTC2CC", "4LSPSRD6YS", "8FGKYWVXHU", "MUHCTAG2P5", "LMUPB2T62S", 
"ULRGP54HCB", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "P6D1DYW1QY", "FVRTMX5FGW", "XP21SPSTTK", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "1XR4KTZ4ZF", "17X8N3R48S", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "YD168YAUHE", 
"RMGQEV5WQG", "L24UXR2W2G", "Q7CX6BFYQ6", "459W995DKU", "8NQLXTPGRB", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "EKH3KN6Z91", "GRADQPHVXP", "K4NHG395WP", "D97CECY7X3", 
"AHZHB4PYA3", "BTY57UEMEG", "8FGKYWVXHU", "MUHCTAG2P5", "4GPMWXTXZT", 
"HTRH2T7F9G", "4LSPSRD6YS", "FVRTMX5FGW", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "WDZ5GHD54Y", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "17X8N3R48S", "XP21SPSTTK", "P6D1DYW1QY", "ULRGP54HCB", 
"GRADQPHVXP", "AHZHB4PYA3", "D97CECY7X3", "L24UXR2W2G", "K4NHG395WP", 
"459W995DKU", "8NQLXTPGRB", "BTY57UEMEG", "AUMZLBBX99", "VVML2TUDCL", 
"EKH3KN6Z91", "2UKFDTC2CC", "WKP5871S4Y", "MUHCTAG2P5", "4LSPSRD6YS", 
"4GPMWXTXZT", "HTRH2T7F9G", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "FVRTMX5FGW", "LZ1114TSZ3", 
"LMUPB2T62S", "ULRGP54HCB", "P6D1DYW1QY", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "17X8N3R48S", 
"XP21SPSTTK", "YD168YAUHE", "8NQLXTPGRB", "L24UXR2W2G", "D97CECY7X3", 
"K4NHG395WP", "AUMZLBBX99", "WKP5871S4Y", "GRADQPHVXP", "EKH3KN6Z91", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "459W995DKU", "BTY57UEMEG", "AHZHB4PYA3", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"4LSPSRD6YS", "P6D1DYW1QY", "4GPMWXTXZT", "XP21SPSTTK", "MUHCTAG2P5", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "FVRTMX5FGW", "17X8N3R48S", 
"ULRGP54HCB", "DHVZ3BQWSL", "YD168YAUHE", "K4NHG395WP", "AHZHB4PYA3", 
"L24UXR2W2G", "459W995DKU", "EKH3KN6Z91", "AUMZLBBX99", "8NQLXTPGRB", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "GRADQPHVXP", "D97CECY7X3", "BTY57UEMEG", "9K67BSQN6B", 
"4LSPSRD6YS", "4GPMWXTXZT", "P6D1DYW1QY", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "XP21SPSTTK", 
"FVRTMX5FGW", "LZ1114TSZ3", "HTRH2T7F9G", "RMGQEV5WQG", "VVML2TUDCL", 
"BTY57UEMEG", "AUMZLBBX99", "D97CECY7X3", "EKH3KN6Z91", "459W995DKU", 
"K4NHG395WP", "YD168YAUHE", "GRADQPHVXP", "AHZHB4PYA3", "8NQLXTPGRB", 
"4GPMWXTXZT", "4LSPSRD6YS", "17X8N3R48S", "P6D1DYW1QY", "HTRH2T7F9G", 
"MUHCTAG2P5", "XP21SPSTTK", "FVRTMX5FGW", "LMUPB2T62S", "1ZNVL8WTS4", 
"LZ1114TSZ3", "RMGQEV5WQG", "K4NHG395WP", "D97CECY7X3", "WKP5871S4Y", 
"VVML2TUDCL", "EKH3KN6Z91", "8NQLXTPGRB", "AHZHB4PYA3", "BTY57UEMEG", 
"YD168YAUHE", "459W995DKU", "HTRH2T7F9G", "FVRTMX5FGW", "4GPMWXTXZT", 
"17X8N3R48S", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "XP21SPSTTK", "4LSPSRD6YS", "P6D1DYW1QY", 
"RMGQEV5WQG", "MUHCTAG2P5", "8NQLXTPGRB", "VVML2TUDCL", "K4NHG395WP", 
"EKH3KN6Z91", "D97CECY7X3", "BTY57UEMEG", "YD168YAUHE", "459W995DKU", 
"FVRTMX5FGW", "4LSPSRD6YS", "17X8N3R48S", "XP21SPSTTK", "4GPMWXTXZT", 
"HTRH2T7F9G", "WDZ5GHD54Y", "P6D1DYW1QY", "L24UXR2W2G", "AHZHB4PYA3", 
"8NQLXTPGRB", "K4NHG395WP", "GRADQPHVXP", "17X8N3R48S", "XP21SPSTTK", 
"1ZNVL8WTS4", "LMUPB2T62S", "8NQLXTPGRB", "EKH3KN6Z91", "K4NHG395WP", 
"L24UXR2W2G", "AHZHB4PYA3", "GRADQPHVXP", "XP21SPSTTK", "L24UXR2W2G", 
"K4NHG395WP", "EKH3KN6Z91", "GRADQPHVXP", "XP21SPSTTK", "17X8N3R48S", 
"L24UXR2W2G", "4LSPSRD6YS", "FVRTMX5FGW", "17X8N3R48S", "XP21SPSTTK", 
"1ZNVL8WTS4", "L24UXR2W2G", "K4NHG395WP", "8NQLXTPGRB", "QZPUSKTTTE", 
"4GPMWXTXZT", "FVRTMX5FGW", "XP21SPSTTK", "1ZNVL8WTS4", "17X8N3R48S", 
"L24UXR2W2G", "8NQLXTPGRB", "K4NHG395WP", "FVRTMX5FGW", "17X8N3R48S", 
"K4NHG395WP", "8NQLXTPGRB", "17X8N3R48S", "K4NHG395WP", "QZPUSKTTTE", 
"N3WKM7VV4Q", "1M42PYDPT2", "1M42PYDPT2", "1M42PYDPT2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2672L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT: This piece of code worked for me

```
DF$trim <- ifelse((ave(DF$SERIAL, DF$SERIAL, FUN = length) >= 15),1,0)
DF$total <- ave(DF$SERIAL, DF$SERIAL, FUN = length)
DF$total <- as.numeric(DF$total)
NEW_DF <- subset(DF, DF$total >= 15)
```

Comment: Please post your data so we can run code with. Paste the output from `dput(df)`

Comment: I suspect you're looking for something like `df %>% group_by(participant) %>% filter(n() > 15)` but without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's really just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have added the output for the row in question. Serial numbers are really just the anonymized participants. I want to remove those serial numbers whose minimum number of times appearing in this row are less than 15.

Answer (score 0):

I unable to reproduce your data, but from what I see this might work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  add_count(SERIAL) %>% 
  filter(n > 15)
```

Comment: ``` data %>% count(SERIAL) data %>% add_count(SERIAL) %>% filter(n >= 15) ``` Using the first piece of code, it measures around 288 total unique serial numbers (which is correct). With your code, it's more like 1500. It basically totals the all the times the serial number appears in the column, then gives that count to each time the serial number appears. However, I modified your code to read "count(SERIAL) %>% 
  filter(n > 15)" which yields the correct results, but now removes every other variable in the DF that isn't serial!